# How set custom css styles in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I try to position my `Grid` `Material-UI` component, without any success, what is wrong here?

```
class Scene extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mystyle = {
        backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
        position: "absolute",
        top: "125px",
        left: "125px",
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px"
    };

    return (
      <div className={mystyle}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs="2">
          <Board init={1} end={2}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Scene;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it seems the thing is wrong is `className={mystyle}`, `mystyle` isn't a "className", but an actual "style" object. Try replacing `className={mystyle}` with `style={mystyle}`, I believe it will work by making all those styles become inline-style in the `div`.

About "How to set custom CSS styles in React?", you can do a quick googling and will find out tons of answers, articles. Like [this article](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822), there're (at least) 4 ways to set style in React:

1. Use Css Stylesheets
2. Inline styling. There're also 2 types of inline-styling: actual inline styling vs via an object (like what you did)
3. CSS Modules
4. Use a `css-in-js` libraries like Styled-components to create "styled components"
5. Use libraries's ways. They might turn a javascript object to a className with React Hooks (likely this's what you actually want in this situation - the Material-UI way)

Answer (score 1):

Either pass it ass `style` attribute or if you are planning to use multiple classes you can use "css-in-js" to style your components [more here - material-ui-docs](https://v3.material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#api)

```js
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const styles {
   mystyle: {
        backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
        position: "absolute",
        top: "125px",
        left: "125px",
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px"
    }
}



class Scene extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.mystyle}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs="2">
          <Board init={1} end={2}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default withStyles(styles)(Scene);
```

or same approuch with hooks

```
// ...
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  mystyle : {
        backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
        position: "absolute",
        top: "125px",
        left: "125px",
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px"
    }
});

function Scene () {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div className={classes.mystyle}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs="2">
          <Board init={1} end={2}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </div>
    );

}

export default Scene;
```

Comment: It seems this is the reason why the OP has made the mistake. Because by using Material-UI library, you'll by chance see someone turn javascript object to CSS class by `makeStyles` hook or `withStyles` HOC. Smell like he's using a UI library before properly knowing React.